# How to properly override the runTest method of python's unittest module

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm working on some code with this setup:

```py
class Base(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Base, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.logger = None

    def runTest(self):
        self.prepare_logging()

    def prepare_logging(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger()
        self.logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        self.logger.debug('Inside Base')

class Child(Base):
    def runTest(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Child, self).runTest(*args, **kwargs)
        fh = logging.FileHandler('./debug.log')
        fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        self.logger.addHandler(fh)
        self.logger.debug('Inside Child')

class GrandChild(Child):
    def test_logger(self):
        self.logger.debug('Inside GrandChild')
```

I have a base class that inherits from TestCase which creates a logger instance and adds some basic functionality to it. I need to find a way to modify the logger instance to add a couple filehandlers within a class that inherits the Base(I can't modify the base class). I need to modify the Child class so that it adds this file handler. Then run the test in the Grandchild class which now has the additional logger functionality. Is there a clean way to do this without modifying the Base class?